# LRN calculation is different between caffe and Tensor Flow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, formula, normalization, caffe

I would like to know if there is a change in the LRN layer implementation in Tensor flow from Caffe implementation.

From the link http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/lrn.html i see that the formula is (1+alpha/n*(sum_of_square))**beta. But in the Tensor Flow documentation here 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/local_response_normalization 
division with n is missing (i.e) sum_of_square value is not divided by n here.

The documentation is missing this part or it's the implementation itself that has been changed in Tensor Flow.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I got the same question, judging from the impl here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e6faa845c51bb69465146d93646947fd2ba53efa/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/lrn_op_test.py#L53 . TF documentation is correct.